Why are my Markdown files being auto-formatted with extra spaces?
I edited a markdown file as
a.md
# Title

## Sub Title

- a
- b
- c

After saving the file, it became:
# Title

## Sub Title

-   a
-   b
-   c

How do I fix it?
It seems that Prettier is autoformatting my markdown files with
noautocmd call prettier#Autoformat()

(from ~/.vim/plugged/vim-prettier/plugin/prettier.vim). Is there a way to disable this behavior or configure prettier to not add extra spaces?

Vim didn't do that on its own. This means that something you installed/copypasted is responsible and that you will have to find it. A first step in your investigation would be to do :verbose autocmd BufWritePre,BufWritePost when in a markdown file, which would tell you what is running on write, as well as where it comes from.

Welcome to Vim :-) Are you using a distribution like NvChad or LazyVim?

That would make it a welcome to Neovim, not to Vim.

@romainl Thank you. It seems the reason is due to Prettier: *.md      noautocmd call prettier#Autoformat() ~/.vim/plugged/vim-prettier/plugin/prettier.vim.

Then the next step would be to figure out if prettier can be configured to not do that and whether it would be best to do it via the Vim plugin or directly.

If you are using LazyVim it format the files before saying.
If you want to disable that you could be interested to the following answer

Thank you. I'm not using LazyVim. It seems the reason is due to Prettier: *.md      noautocmd call prettier#Autoformat() ~/.vim/plugged/vim-prettier/plugin/prettier.vim.
